# Select all UDFs from database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, view, user-defined-functions, system-views

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.functions
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for SQLServer2005 it is:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE type in ('TF','FN','IF')
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will give you all the details of the udfs you've created.

```
SELECT *
    FROM
        sysobjects
    WHERE
        (type = 'TF' OR type = 'FN' OR type = 'IF')
        AND
        objectproperty(id, 'IsMSShipped') = 0
```

Get rid of the second condition if you want everything.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the names and the definitions :

```
SELECT SPECIFIC_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
```

Comment: ROUTINE_DEFINITION is not reliable. It's only nvarchar(4000), actual def is nvarchar(max)